# Can one process use multiple cors at the same time in parallel?

Tags: linux, mac, cpu, node.js, compile

I'm still a bit hazy with my understanding of a computer processor in relation to the work of a process. Being specific, I plan on getting a new computer and ultimately want to get the fastest compile time for an Angular Typescript environment (with a Mac in mind).

Ultimately I hope to figure out 2 things,

1. Will getting more CPU cores increase my code compilation speed for my compilation process? (or will the kernel just allocate that extra computing power to other background processes not in focus)
2. If the above is true, is it automatic or are there low level options that I need to pass in to make this happen? For reference, I'm depending on **TSLoader** (from javascript Webpack) to compile my code.

If it is not as simple as the above two, I'm hoping I can get a listed answer on the factors that matter.

---

So far I understand that to compile my typescript code, a Node.js env process will be created to compile my code.

```
input files     Process                                           Output
.ts         -> (Webpack -> TSLoader) ->                           .js
               (Node:JIT of Webpack.js to Machine Code)
               (Kernel notices window is in focus?? and prioritizes??)
               (sends to one or multiple cores??? Hazyness... ???)
               (????)
```

Comment: A process can benefit from multiple cores its it can run several threads. But AFAIK compilers are mostly single-threaded but you can have several running in parallel on distinct compilation units. Otherwise, see [this](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#parallelising-builds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not a single process can make use of more than one core depends entirely upon how it is coded.  If it has been coded to break its work up into multiple parallizable parts and allocate each part to a separate thread, then the OS can use different CPU cores for those different threads.

On the other hand, if the process has not been coded to specifically use multiple threads that can each proceed mostly independently (without waiting for results form other threads), then the OS can't really use multiple cores for that process.  Those other cores will get used for other things going on in the system (other apps, background services, etc...), but not for your main app.  Compiling an individual file is not super parallelizable onto multiple cores.

But, if you're looking at a project compilation involving many files, then the more likely way to use multiple cores would be to separately compile multiple files in parallel using build tools that have that capability (Microsoft calls these build orchestration tools).  Here's a [mini discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12987) on the topic.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Now I'm more focused on getting single threaded speed on my next computer. : )